# How much of an array is stored within a cache line?

Tags: c++, arrays, caching

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

struct UIContainer { 
  uint16_t x, y;  //Position on the screen
  uint16_t h, w;  //Height and width of the UIContainer
  uint16_t color; //Color, rgba such as 0xFF000000 & color is red, 0x00FF0000 is green, 0x0000FF00 is blue, 0x000000FF is alpha
  uint16_t ID;    //Unique ID of the ui container    
}; //16 bytes big


void drawUI(UIContainer _container, SDL_Renderer* _renderer) {
    SDL_Rect rect {.x = _container.x, .y = _container.y, .h = _container.h, .w = _container.w }
    uint8_t r = color & 0xFF000000;
    uint8_t g = color & 0x00FF0000;
    uint8_t b = color & 0x0000FF00;
    uint8_t a = color & 0x000000FF;

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(_renderer, r, g, b, a);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(_renderer, &rect); 
}

int main()
{
   UIContainer UIContainers[1024]; //16 * 1024 is 16384 bytes = 16 kilobytes
   SDL_Renderer* renderer; //Pretend it is initialized

   //Draw all the UI
   int i = 0;
   for(i; i < 1024; ++i) {
       drawUI(_container, renderer); 
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I've decided to try and learn about data localization and how to increase the utilization of the cache. Assuming the L1 cache is 64 KB, I am right to assume that the entire array of UIContainer will be loaded into cache, since 16KB is less than 64KB? And if the cache line is 128 Bytes, that would be 8 UIContainer blocks per line?

As I understand it, a cache miss happens when something is not currently in cache. Does this also apply for cache lines? For example, I am operating on container[3] and then I want to skip ahead to container[100], that would cause a cache miss because it has to skip to whatever cache line container[100] is located in?

Finally, assume I exctracted all of the inner parts of UIContainer into their own separate arrays, so that the code now looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

struct location {
  uint16_t x, y;  //Position on the screen
}; //4 bytes

struct size {
  uint16_t h, w;  //Height and width of the UIContainer
}; //4 bytes

struct color {
  uint32_t color; //Color, rgba such as 0xFF000000 & color is red, 0x00FF0000 is green, 0x0000FF00 is blue, 0x000000FF is alpha
} //4 bytes

struct UIContainer {
  uint32_t ID;    //Unique ID of the ui container    
}; //4 bytes


void drawUI(location l, size s, color c, SDL_Renderer* _renderer) {
    SDL_Rect rect {.x = l.x, .y = l.y, .h = s.h, .w = s.w }
    uint8_t r = c & 0xFF000000;
    uint8_t g = c & 0x00FF0000;
    uint8_t b = c & 0x0000FF00;
    uint8_t a = c & 0x000000FF;

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(_renderer, r, g, b, a);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(_renderer, &rect); 
}

int main()
{
   UIContainer UIContainers[1024]; //4 * 1024 is 4048 bytes = 4 kilobytes
   location _location[1024];    //4 KB
   size _size[1024];            //4KB
   color _color[1024];          //4KB
   //////////////////////////////////////// 16 KB Total



   SDL_Renderer* renderer; //Pretend it is initialized

   //Draw all the UI
   int i = 0;
   for(i; i < 1024; ++i) {
       drawUI(_location[i], _size[i], _color[i], renderer); 
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Would this cause cache misses? I wouldn't think it would, since _location[], _size[] and _color[] are all in the cache, and being accessed linearly? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you implementing a compiler? If not, you should probably not care as long as the data is laid out contiguously until you prove a problem by measurement.

Comment: "You should probably not care" is literally the worst thing to ever suggest, especially when "I've decided to try and learn about data localization and how to increase the utilization of the cache."

Comment: Cache behavior is not entirely predictable and extremely complex.  You may want to take a look at [what every programmer needs to know about memory](https://lwn.net/Articles/250967/) to get an idea of how it works.

Comment: Well, until you see (by measurement) that some code is too slow for your specific use case, optimizing your specific code is a waste of time. Cache utilization itself is a pretty complex field (as all of instruction level optimization is) that does not (or should not) depend on your "high-level" code beside contiguous/non-contiguous data layout. If you do in deed implement a compiler, you must care, if not, the compiler should (and will, if decent) care for you. This will not really be related to your specific code, but rather to how specific C++ syntax should be translated to assembly.

Comment: @Baum That's a bad advice. If you care about high performance, you really need to consider cache behavior in your algorithms. Let say if I would implement software rasterizer, I know (without measurement) that I should use swizzled texture layout instead of linear for better cache coherency and performance. Compiler wont improve the cache coherency of your algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

First things first

```
struct UIContainer  {
  uint16_t x, y;  //Position on the screen
  uint16_t h, w;  //Height and width of the UIContainer
  uint16_t color; //Color 
  uint16_t ID;    //Unique ID of the ui container
}; //16 bytes big
static_assert(sizeof(struct UIContainer) == 12, "12 hmm not the case");
static_assert(sizeof(struct UIContainer) == 16, "16 hmm not the case"); // fails, because the last 2 should be uint32_t???
```

> I've decided to try and learn about data localization and how to
>   increase the utilization of the cache. Assuming the L1 cache is 64 KB,
>   I am right to assume that the entire array of UIContainer will be
>   loaded into cache, since 16KB is less than 64KB?

Your UIContainer is an automatic variable and the elements have no constructor so the array will not be automatically loaded into the cache.

- if it had been global, the container or the elements had a constructor then it would have been initialized and therefore during the initialization loaded into the cache.
- had it been initialized earlier it might also have been washed out of the cache by code running after the initialization but before your code.

> And if the cache line is 128 Bytes, that would be 8 UIContainer blocks per line?

- if you have a 128 bytes cache line
- the containers are 16 bytes
- **and** they are aligned to the container size ie. 16 bytes

then you would have 8 containers per cache line.

> As I understand it, a cache miss happens when something is not
>   currently in cache. Does this also apply for cache lines? 
>   For example, I am operating on container[3] and then I want to skip ahead to
>   container[100], that would cause a cache miss because it has to skip
>   to whatever cache line container[100] is located in?

The cache consists of cache lines, which are copies of main memory. When you read about loading cache lines it is really loading data *into* cache lines as they are a physical part of the cache.

- a cache miss is when no cache line in the cache contains the address of the requested data.
- the cache then request the next lower cache or main memory to forward the data.
- main memory with DDR3 would typically send 8*8 bytes, which is also the typical cache line size! having a 128 bytes cache line size would cause it to make 2 burst on continuous addresses.
- memory and lower caches really like continuous address access which gives the highest through put.
- L1 caches are nearly as good on random access as with streaming.

Assuming only your program runs on this processor:

- You will get a minimum of cache *compulsory misses* equal to the number of touched cache lines. As none of your data will be in the cache.
- If you access more cache lines than the cache can hold you will get that many *capacity misses*.
- Further if you access the same address % CacheLineSize more than the associativeness of the cache times you get *conflict misses*. For your 64K cache you will most likely have 8-ways or 16-ways as the cache is most likely divided into page size (4096 bytes) pieces, in this case 16.

> Would this cause cache misses? I wouldn't think it would, since
>   _location[], _size[] and _color[] are all in the cache, and being accessed linearly? Or am I missing something?

You *never* know that something is in the cache, but if you have recently accessed it the likelihood of it being there is higher, this is called spatial and temporal locality.

You can only ever say which one is best if you measure/profile it, and then there can be a tiny change in the code that turns it around.

When you stream the data like in the last code, the cache is generally happy, but there are some gotcha here

- you are taking 3 different data sources(arrays), many architectures only support 2 prefetch streams at a time.
- for your small example there should be no difference, once the size of your active data set exceed the L1 data cache size you will be severely hit.
- as all access is actually in cache line size between the different cache line levels (and memory) using a small part of a cache line cost the same as using it all.

  - in both of your examples any access to lower level cache will be good as the program will use everything in the cache lines *except* the ID, which *might* make the 2nd program run faster as it needs to access 25% fewer cache lines, but you can't be sure before you measured it under worst case conditions.
  - using arrays instead of linked lists is usually a great improvement to any program so don't change that.

More gory details on [caches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache)

I haven't seen any 128 bytes cache lines, but then again I mostly see Intel and AMD.

Answer (score 2):

The amount of an array stored in a processor's cache depends on the size of the array (in bytes) and the capacity of the processor's data cache and any left-over data from other structures.

Sorry, but there is no standard data cache size.  For that matter, there is no requirement that all platforms have a data cache.

Usually, data cache is only important when performing many math operations on the same set of data.  For example, a search through an array won't justify the use of the data cache.  The data may be loaded and only one pass made.  Other operations, such as data smoothing, Fast Fourier Transforms, and Matrix rotations, involve more than one access to the data.  The performance boost comes in after the first pass of the data.

The best method is to profile your present code, write down the average run-time.  Change your code for better use of the data cache.  Profile again.  Compare the results to the first (original execution).

I changed the layout of data, to be more data cache friendly, in one of my programs and it increased performance by 30%.

**Edit 1:**
To answer the question, per title, the amount of data stored in a cache line is the amount that the program is accessing.  Some processors may fetch more, some may not.  Depends on what is already in the cache, the processor's cache loading algorithm, the capacity of a cache line and the capacity of the data cache.

Answer (score 2):

You will always get cache misses when you access data for the first time. After that it depends on traits of the cache (cache and cache line size, associativity, etc.) and memory access pattern (linear, random, etc.) if the data is still in the cache. Generally it's better to keep data you read in close proximity from each other so that as much useful data is read in one cache line fetch as possible. For example you have 3 arrays (_location, _size, _color) that you access linearly but it would be more efficient from cache point of view to use interleaved data format where you have a single array with location, size and color data interleaved next to each other. While in theory you should get the same amount of cache misses in both non-interleaved and interleaved cases, your drawUI() function may cause some of the data to be evicted from cache, or some other processes running on the background may flush the data from the cache. Also another thing to keep in mind is that processor will try to predict your access pattern and prefetch data to cache to avoid memory stalls.

That being said, you need to consider if the potentially added complexity to increase cache coherency is really worth it. If you have some very high performance loops that have potentially big impact on performance, sure. But in many cases it doesn't gain you much and it's not worth the effort and added complexity to worry too much about it. Some people will tell you to profile and then decide to optimize for cache if it seems necessary. However, many of us developing software in the real world don't have the luxury of writing the same algorithm multiple times and have to take educated guesses where it matters based on our experience. So while premature optimization is root of all evil, belated pessimization is the leaf of no good.